# visual studio 2015 c# not break on unhandled exception in formload method

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

my main method like these:

```
static void Main()
        {
            throw new Exception("dsfs");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new ImageSettings());
        }
```

and when debug,it will be stop and tips like the following:
[image]

but when i try to throw a exception in form load method like these:

```
private void ImageSettings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("sdfds");
            ...
}
```

visual studio won't stop and tip, it will directly exit the program.
so how can i set the visual studio and let it also stop a unhandled exception in form lifecycle method ? (and handled exception i do not want to stop and break)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this is "by design" and has to do with how the form load event is invoked.

Comment: You need to add the necessary try/catch blocks yourself in that particular event and decide on how to handle exceptions.